# JQuery Mobile Listview Element Disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a JQuery Mobile web-app that populates a listview dynamically.

The problem that I am having, is that my list elements are not displaying with the enhanced JQuery Mobile look, so I added `$("#landmarksList").listview("refresh");` and they are now displaying correctly.

My problem is I get the following error when I click the back button from one of the row elements.

> Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

```
error (jquery-2.1.1.js, line 250)
(anonymous function) (jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js, line 1013)
each (jquery-2.1.1.js, line 375)
each (jquery-2.1.1.js, line 139)
(anonymous function) (jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js, line 1005)
(anonymous function) (landmarks.js, line 80)
fire (jquery-2.1.1.js, line 3073)
add (jquery-2.1.1.js, line 3119)
ready (jquery-2.1.1.js, line 3352)
assembleRows (landmarks.js, line 72)
```

Page that Displays Error: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B6/landmarks.html

The confusing thing about this is that it loads correctly, without the error, the first time the page displays, and then displays this error when a page is trying to return to the first page.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the `listview` method first without a parameter:

```
$('#landmarksList').listview().listview('refresh');
```

Comment: I tried that, and it still shows the error. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the link in the question. Now when you click the back button, the listview appears blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved my problem with the disappearing listview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221484/jquery-mobile-ui-overlay-hiding-elements