# JQuery Mobile ui-overlay Hiding Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a JQuery Mobile web-app and am running into an interesting problem. My web-app dynamically populates a list-view from JSON data.

The problem: When the user taps on an element in the listview in Page 1, Page 2 loads fine, however, when they tap on the "Back" button, Page 1 does not display correctly.

I initially thought that the rows were not being populated, however I have not figured out that they are being hidden by the JQuery Mobile CSS: (starting on line 946 of JQuery Mobile 1.4.2.css which can be found here: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B7/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css)

```
/* Page and overlay */
.ui-overlay-a,
.ui-page-theme-a,
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color:           #f9f9f9 /*{a-page-background-color}*/;
    border-color:           #bbb /*{a-page-border}*/;
    color:                  #333 /*{a-page-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-page-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-page-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-page-shadow-radius}*/     #f3f3f3 /*{a-page-shadow-color}*/;
}
```

Page that experiences problem: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B7/landmarks.html
JavaScript  that renders the menu rows: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B7/js/landmarks.js

I have noticed that if the `background-color` is commented out, the rows appear (but other visual errors occur), however, they seem to be in a lower layer of the page.

Any ideas about what might be causing this layering issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this ended up being a problem with the back button on the details pages.

The back button code was originally:

```
<a href="#landmarks" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">Back</a>
```

However, I believe the `href` and the `data-rel` were conflicting. I removed the `data-rel` and kept the `href` and the problem with the page layering went away.

Moral of the story: if you know what page to go back to (and do not rely on the browser's history) it is better to `href` to the page, as there will be less conflicts.